# Register to support location document type in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, uti

I am trying to find out the `LSItemContentTypes` to be have a location in the maps app share to my app.

As an example of what I require is:

- searching for a location in maps
- tapping on the pin
- tap on the info button
- Share in the top right

This only provides Messages, Mail, Twitter and Facebook.

Does anyone know if this is a public document UTI type? And if so what is the identifier?

I have tried com.apple.maps, public.contact, public.url, public.vcard and I can't see anything applicable on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html